# Galen framework is not recognizing the correct area of webelements

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests, galen

I am using Galen framework for layout testing along with java selenium cucumber framework.
Some information that might be useful- I have a 34-inch monitor but while running my test, I resize my browser window to 1440px width and 900px height.
When I run my tests, the html report is generated fine.
But in the report, the highlighted area for elements is always misaligned.
This results in incorrect measurement of the element dimensions.
Below is an example , I have hidden some confidential information.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7NVq.png)
Notice in the above image how the box for the element is misaligned.

I was expecting Galen to generate accurate boxes highlighting element.
I have tried changing the size of the browser window but the highlighted area remained misaligned.
I also tried checking multiple elements but those were also misaligned.